# Installing NodeJS LTS for Ansible

Tags: node.js, ansible, ansible-role

I'm looking for an appropriate Ansible Role or Ansible YAML file for installing NodeJS LTS on a Ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial system. I tried more than 10 Ansible roles from Galaxy but didn't find any of them working (throws error such as `potentially dangerous to add this PPA etc.`.

Can anyone provide any Ansible playbook or suggest me a role to install NodeJS LTS on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Do you know what are the steps to install it without Ansible? If so, why don't you create your own role?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  vars:
    NODEJS_VERSION: "8"
  tasks:
    - name: Install the gpg key for nodejs LTS
      apt_key:
        url: "https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key"
        state: present
    
    - name: Install the nodejs LTS repos
      apt_repository:
        repo: "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_{{ NODEJS_VERSION }}.x {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main"
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install the nodejs
      apt:
        name: nodejs
        state: present
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: it somehow works but shows the error `"msg": "unsupported parameter for module: filename"`. Any idea?

Comment: try now, which version of ansible are you using?

Comment: I'm using `ansible 2.0.0.2`

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded ansible to `2.3.2.0` and it worked.

Comment: what are the possible values for the var `ansible_distribution_release`?

Comment: the values of `ansible_distribution_release` might be `trusty` `xenial` etc

Comment: I got the following error message, "The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.* xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data fro
m such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use".  I "fixed" it by adding allow_unauthenticated: yes to my apt task.  Is there a better way of fixing this?

Comment: @TimStewart updated the answer, can you please try that. also tell me the version of ansible that you are using. I have tested it with ansible 2.4.x

Comment: You don't need to set the `ansible_distribution_release` variable- Ansible should feed that variable in without the line there at all

Comment: How ansible wil know that we need to install the node repo for trusty or xenial etc?

Comment: The following task should be added - the installation of "transport-https"     


- name: Ensure apt-transport-https is installed.
  apt:
      name: apt-transport-https
      state: present

Comment: Adding `gather_facts: True` to the playbook solved `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_distribution_release' is undefined. 'ansible_distribution_release' is undefined`

Answer (score 8):

Not that I am really happy with having had to do this, but...

(**env:  Ubuntu 18.04, ansible 2.6.1, host: macOS** )

from https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

```
- name: install node 
  shell: |
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

result:

```
> vagrant@vagrant:~$ node --version
v10.15.2
```

and `npm` must have come along too:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ npm --version
6.4.1
```

At the time I ran this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm was showing **6.8.0** as latest, with **6.4.1** being from 6 months before.  Node was showing **10.15.2** as latest in 10.x series, dating 5 days before.

btw, I also tried `apt-get` but that ended with node 8.x rather than 10.x

And the reason I didn't use an ansible galaxy role is that I didn't see any nodejs ones that seemed to come from well-known authors and with lots of stars and downloads (I am cautious and suspicious).

#### updating npm

My dev machine had `6.8.0` so I added this:

**vars.yml**:

```
versions:
  npm: "6.8.0"
```

**playbook.yml**:

```
- name: npm self-update
  command: npm install npm@{{ versions.npm }} -g
```

which got me all the way to:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ npm --version
6.8.0
```

Comment: Can you explain why you selected this approach over the selected answer?

Comment: Less installation of new stuff and it’s after all from the node’s team own instructions.  I am not saying the accepted answer is bad, and I am not that strong in Ansible, but I considered it a simple shell command so I did it and moved on.  Not that concerned about idempotence either, this server will be rebuilt rather than maintained.  I would still strongly avoid, for security, any third-tier Galaxy role or random PPA though that is not an issue with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is good, but if you want you can use discovered variables for the distro codename (namely `ansible_lsb.codename`). Also, ensuring that `gcc g++ make` are installed on the host machine ensures native addons for nodejs will work properly.

Just replace node version `12` with what you'd like.

```
---
- name: Install nodejs
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: install nodejs prerequisites
      apt:
        name:
          - apt-transport-https
          - gcc
          - g++
          - make
        state: present
    - name: add nodejs apt key
      apt_key:
        url: https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key
        state: present
    - name: add nodejs repository
      apt_repository:
        repo: deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} main
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
    - name: install nodejs
      apt:
        name: nodejs
        state: present
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I used `{{ ansible_distribution_release }}` instead of `{{ ansible_lsb.codename }}` and had to use `state: latest` because `state: present` doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`ansible-galaxy install nodesource.node`

and then on your playbook, add

  `roles:
    - nodesource.node`

Comment: For all who puts "-", please describe why. I don't see any problems with this suggestion. It does not work or what?

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy For start, it appears to be incomplete. Question asked about Ansible playbook and here there is a manual unexplained installation step (`ansible-galaxy`). Maybe it is obvious what it is doing, but I am here because I am na Ansible newbie.

Comment: answer seems outdated...it raises this [error](https://github.com/nodesource/ansible-nodejs-role/issues/45#issuecomment-589018900)

Comment: use [this one](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/nodejs) instead